# Proper use of wait and notify methods in Java threading

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I am new to Java multithreading. I created simple producer-consumer pattern using wait and notify but my producer is getting called only once in tbe starting.

```
public class ThreadApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ProducerConsumerWorldp = new ProducerConsumerWorld();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    p.producer();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    p.consumer();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
    }
}
class ProducerConsumerWorld{
    public void producer() throws InterruptedException{
        synchronized (this) {
            while(true){
                System.out.println("Producer thread started running");
                wait();
                System.out.println("Resumed Producing");
            }
        }
    }
    public void consumer() throws InterruptedException{
        synchronized (this) {
            while(true){
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                System.out.println("Consumer thread started running");
                System.out.println("Press enter to consume all and start producing");
                Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
                s.nextLine();
                notify();
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                System.out.println("consumed all");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am creating separate threads for producer and consumer. Producer thread only gets called in the starting and then after it is never getting executed.

I tried two option to overcome this issue. first I put while condition outside of synchronized block second is given below.

```
class ProducerConsumerWorld{
    public void producer() throws InterruptedException{
        synchronized (this) {
            while(true){
                System.out.println("Producer thread started running");
                notify();
                wait();
                System.out.println("Resumed Producing");
            }
        }
    }
    public void consumer() throws InterruptedException{
        synchronized (this) {
            while(true){
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                System.out.println("Consumer thread started running");
                System.out.println("Press enter to consume all and start producing");
                Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
                s.nextLine();
                notify();
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                System.out.println("consumed all");
                wait();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Both works great. Which one the of the appropriate solution to use ? I am still unable to figure out why the code I put in question is not working properly.

Comment: And don't see separate threads for consumer and producer - I can just see two methods...and clearly, the `main` class/method which executes the program is missing here.

Comment: @AKSW : I am not putting the code of main mehtods as I am just creating two seperate threads there for consumer and producer.

Comment: Forget `wait () `and `notify () `, they're a very low level mechanism. You'd be better off learning the high level stuff in the JDK, eg use `BlockingQueue` to manage your producers and consumers.

Comment: @daniu thanks for the suggestion. I know about BlockingQueue. It is that I want to learn how to deal with low level sync. to hava a better grasp of multithreading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am still unable to figure out why the code I put in question is not working properly

The `wait()` in `producer()` releases the monitor which allows `consumer()` to enter its `synchronized` block. Then the `wait()` in `producer()` starts waiting till `consumer()` calls `notify()` **and** releases the monitor (i.e. exits its `synchronized` block). You never exit `synchronized` in `consumer()` therefore the `wait()` in `producer()` is blocked forever

Comment: why could my code never exit from cousumer. I have put notify() in the last if you see

Comment: @HarshKanakhara I said you never exit the `synchronized` block in consumer. You have an infinite loop inside `synchronized` in consumer. Yes you call notify() but you forever stay inside `synchronized` in consumer. Therefore wait() in producer cannot return.

Answer (score 1):

> I am still unable to figure out why the code I put in question is not
> working properly

I've managed to fix your code, and I've attached below the fixed code snippet.

I've introduced a boolean instance variable named isConsumed for the ProducerConsumerWorld. In doing so, what essentially happens is that after Producer Thread produces, he updates the state of isConsumed to false, since he has produced something which is yet to be consumed. Afterwards, the producer notifies the the Consumer thread, that Producer has finished producing. Next, it invokes wait() on the ProducerConsumerWorld which releases Producer's lock on ProducerConsumerWorld. Then, it waits for the lock on ProducerConsumerWorld.

Meanwhile, the Consumer Thead acquires the lock on ProducerConsumerWorld, which allows it to enter the consumer method, where it checks if there is produce yet to be consumed. If so, it consumes and updates the isConsumed variable to true, and notifies the produce has been consumed. Then the consumer proceeds to releases its lock on ProducerConsumerWorld by calling wait(), and waits to reacquire the lock on ProducerConsumerWorld after Producer has consumed.

Note:

> Calling notify() doesn't release a lock until the thread moves out of the synchronized block, or wait() is called, thus releasing the lock.
>
> *Source: Oracle's OCA/OCP Java SE 7 Study Guide Page 760*

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ThreadApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ProducerConsumerWorld p = new ProducerConsumerWorld();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    p.producer();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    p.consumer();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
class ProducerConsumerWorld{

    boolean consumed = false;

    public void producer() throws InterruptedException{
        System.out.println("Producer thread started running");
        synchronized (this) {
            while(this.consumed == true){ // Consumer has consumed and is waiting for produce
                System.out.println("Resumed Producing");
                this.consumed = false;
                notify();
                wait();
            }
        }
    }
    public void consumer() throws InterruptedException{
        synchronized (this) {
            while(this.consumed == false){
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                System.out.println("Consumer thread started running");
                System.out.println("Press enter to consume all and start producing");
                Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
                s.nextLine();
                this.consumed = true;
                System.out.println("consumed all");
                notify(); 
                wait();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This gives me an output like,

[image]

Comment: thanks for this solution but i don't want to use any 3rd variable then there is not point of using wait and notify methods. I can simple use synchronized blocks and make my variable volatile to make it work.

Comment: It's not my area of expertise, but this looks like a good answer. However, please do not ask for upvotes in answers here - we regard this as "fluff" that needs removing. If you believe that the question author does not know about voting, then you can remind them in the comments, but remember that it is optional.

Comment: Thanks @halfer , I'll be mindful of it the next time. Please excuse the newbie in me :')